# Detect when dialog sets focus to various combo controls using PreTranslateMessage

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, setfocus

I have a `CDialog` and I am trying to override `PreTranslateMessage` like this:

```
BOOL CWeekendMeetingDlg::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
{

    if (pMsg->message == WM_SETFOCUS)
    {
        if (::GetDlgCtrlID(pMsg->hwnd) != IDC_COMBO_PT_CHAIRMAN &&
            ::GetDlgCtrlID(pMsg->hwnd) != IDC_COMBO_PT_OPEN_PRAYER &&
            ::GetDlgCtrlID(pMsg->hwnd) != IDC_COMBO_WT_CLOSE_PRAYER &&
            ::GetDlgCtrlID(pMsg->hwnd) != IDC_COMBO_WEEKEND_HOST &&
            ::GetDlgCtrlID(pMsg->hwnd) != IDC_COMBO_WEEKEND_COHOST &&
            ::GetDlgCtrlID(pMsg->hwnd) != IDC_COMBO_PT_READER)
        {
            if (m_gridAssignHist.GetRowCount() != 1)
            {
                m_gridAssignHist.SetRowCount(1);
            }
        }
    }

    return CDialog::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}
```

It is not working. What I want to do is reset my `CGridCtrl` row count to 1 when other controls gain focus (eg: edit combo). But if I put a breakpoint inside the first `if` it is never intercepted.

At the moment the only thing I can think of is to renumber all of the combo IDs on the dialog so they are sequential and then use a command range for `OnSetFocus` and detect in that handler. But there are also some `CEdit` controls.

Can't I use PTM though and avoid that? For me it seems it would be the easiest.

Here is the dialog:

[image]

At the moment I have 7 combo `OnSetFocus` handlers. When they fire the display specific assignment history in the grid on the right.

So if the user moves to any other control on the dialog, the assignment history control will not apply. And that was why i wanted to reset the history to just the header row. And I was hoping to do this with PTM.

Comment: You could use [CBN_SETFOCUS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/cbn-setfocus) directly.

Comment: @dxiv, Sorry, that is what I meant and I have implemented those handlers for that message for my specific combos. I think I found a solution.

Comment: Not sure why the plural for "*handlers*". CBN_SETFOCUS would be caught in the parent window (the dialog) and all child IDs would need just one handler in your case.

Comment: @dxiv Yes, I get you, but I still have the other types of controls to detect. I think the timer is a simple enough resolution.

Comment: Not sure about that, but it's too long for a comment so I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Child control notifications are received in the parent dialog via `WM_COMMAND` messages. Overriding MFC dialog's `OnCommand` catches those notifications ([CBN_SETFOCUS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/cbn-setfocus), [EN_SETFOCUS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/en-setfocus) etc).

```
void DoSomething()
{   /* ... */ }

BOOL CWeekendMeetingDlg::OnCommand(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM /*unused*/)
{
    switch (HIWORD(wParam))
    {
    case CBN_SETFOCUS:
        switch (LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        case IDC_COMBO_PT_CHAIRMAN:
        // ...more combobox IDCs
            DoSomething();
            break; // or return TRUE to bypass any message map handlers
        }
        break;

    case EN_SETFOCUS:
        switch (LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        case IDC_EDIT_WHATEVER:
        // ...more editbox IDCs
            DoSomething();
            break;
        }
        break;

    // ...more notification codes
    }
    return CDialog::OnCommand(wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. It looks like I need to handle CBN_DROPDOWN for the combo boxes that are drop lists, and BN_SETFOCUS for the buttons. Will update you.

Answer (score 0):

I have added a 2 second timer to the dialog:

```
void CWeekendMeetingDlg::OnTimer(UINT_PTR nIDEvent)
{
    if (nIDEvent == 1)
    {
        CWnd* pControl = GetFocus();
        if (pControl != nullptr)
        {
            CWnd* pParent = pControl->GetParent();
            if (pParent != nullptr)
            {
                int iCtrlID = pParent->GetDlgCtrlID();

                if (iCtrlID != IDC_COMBO_PT_CHAIRMAN &&
                    iCtrlID != IDC_COMBO_PT_OPEN_PRAYER &&
                    iCtrlID != IDC_COMBO_WT_CLOSE_PRAYER &&
                    iCtrlID != IDC_COMBO_WEEKEND_HOST &&
                    iCtrlID != IDC_COMBO_WEEKEND_COHOST &&
                    iCtrlID != IDC_COMBO_PT_READER)
                {
                    if (m_gridAssignHist.GetRowCount() != 1)
                    {
                        m_gridAssignHist.SetRowCount(1);

                        UpdateData(TRUE);
                        m_strAssignHistLabel = _T("Assignment:");
                        UpdateData(FALSE);
                    }
                }

            }

        }

    }

    CDialog::OnTimer(nIDEvent);
}
```

This seems to work fine.